# What determines the quality of crafting materials gathered?

Tags: the-division

I would certainly like to get the best crafting materials, but everything I'm gathering right now is green or blue quality. You can use them to craft higher quality materials, but given the numbers required that doesn't seem feasible. **Is there a way to influence the quality of crafting materials my character gathers?**

Comment: Pure speculation but I'm guessing deconstructing higher level weapons and armor will result in higher level materials. Also maybe higher level districts may have better material loot? Finally the character level might have some hidden effect on the chance of quality. And of course we're all at the mercy of RNGesus.

Comment: True, but I have't noticed much of a difference there (granted, I'm only level 13). Weapons seem to by and large deconstruct to only weapon parts, and fabric for armor. Perhaps mods would provide a better source for blue or higher quality electronics/whatnot, but I don't really find those in enough quantities right now for it to really make that seem viable. I guess this will remain an open question

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'll always be the case that Weapons > Weapon Parts and Amour > Fabric.
Oh yeah I deconstructed a few mods last night (grey/green) and got `Tools` from them. Green quality I think but certainly _not_ blue.

Answer (score 2):

Normally wou will get items in the color of the destroyed item. Green gives green, blue gives blue.
If you got to the DZ to get purple or even yellow items, you will get those materials upon destruction (or by levelling them, as explained in the question)

Edit on personal experience:
Purple items only give blue material. There is no purple material in the game (yet). But you can increase your chance for better material by using  the passive "skill" scavenging.

Comment: There are no purple materials though, so you get blue from deconstructing purple gear